# Stack matrix on the third dimension numpy

Tags: python, numpy, stack, repeat

I have a matrix `W` which I want to repeat and stack it `x` times on the third axis. What is the easiest way to do so? I can do it in two code rows, was wondering if it can be done in one:

```
np.repeat(W,x,axis=1)
W=W.reshape(W.shap[0],W.shap[1],x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new and empty axis (with np.[newaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis)) and than repeat along this axis.

```
W = np.repeat(W[:, :, np.newaxis], x, axis=2)
```